# What is the correct syntax for NotificationCenter to return batteryLevel and batteryState in Swift 3.1

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotification, batterylevel, notificationcenter

I'm a newbie to Swift (using Xcode 8.3.3, Swift 3.1) and I'm trying to display battery level and battery state and update them when the values change. Here's what I have so far:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myBatteryPercent: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var myBatteryState: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true


    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("batteryLevelDidChange:")),
     name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange,
     object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("batteryStateDidChange:")),
     name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChange,
     object: nil)

    var batteryLevel: Float {
        return UIDevice.current.batteryLevel
    }

    var batteryState: UIDeviceBatteryState {
        return UIDevice.current.batteryState
    }

    switch batteryState {
    case .unplugged, .unknown:
        myBatteryState.text = "not charging"
    case .charging, .full:
        myBatteryState.text = "charging or full"
    }

    myBatteryPercent.text = "\(Int((batteryLevel) * 100))%"



    func batteryLevelDidChange (notification: Notification) {
        myBatteryPercent.text = "\(Int((batteryLevel) * 100))%"
    }
    func batteryStateDidChange (notification: Notification) {
        switch batteryState {
        case .unplugged, .unknown:
            myBatteryState.text = "not charging"
        case .charging, .full:
            myBatteryState.text = "charging or full"
        }
    }    
}
```

My app crashes when either the level or state changes generating this error message: [Battery_Display.ViewController batteryLevelDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100b0cf10'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're wrong with a placement of the notification handlers. The handlers are declared inside `viewDidLoad` method and they are out of scope for `NotificationCenter` singleton.
Just put them out of `viewDidLoad` and it should work:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myBatteryPercent: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myBatteryState: UILabel!
    var batteryLevel: Float {
        return UIDevice.current.batteryLevel
    }

    var batteryState: UIDeviceBatteryState {
        return UIDevice.current.batteryState
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true


        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(batteryLevelDidChange), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(batteryStateDidChange), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChange, object: nil)

        switch batteryState {
        case .unplugged, .unknown:
            myBatteryState.text = "not charging"
        case .charging, .full:
            myBatteryState.text = "charging or full"
        }

        myBatteryPercent.text = "\(Int((batteryLevel) * 100))%"

    }

    func batteryLevelDidChange (notification: Notification) {
        myBatteryPercent.text = "\(Int((batteryLevel) * 100))%"
    }

    func batteryStateDidChange (notification: Notification) {
        switch batteryState {
        case .unplugged, .unknown:
            myBatteryState.text = "not charging"
        case .charging, .full:
            myBatteryState.text = "charging or full"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to make them public also.

Comment: @DavidShaw I just checked my code and it's working well

Comment: @daMachine you can accept the answer if it's working